# What is the non-asymptotic upper bound for the leading eigenvector of the random matrix?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Fix a Gaussian random matrix $A$ with $E[A_{ij}]=0$ for $i, j=1,\dots n$ and $E[A_{ij}^2]=\frac{1}{n}$. Let $v_1$ be the leading eigenvector of $A$. What is the non-asymptotic upper bound for $v_1$, that is something like
$$
P(v_1\cdot u\ge t)\le e^{-\alpha t}
$$
where $u$ is distributed uniformly on the unit sphere.

Is there any reference for this tail probability? Thank you!

---

Let $\{v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n\}$ be the  eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n$ of a matrix $A$  from GOE. Each of the eigenvectors $v_1,\dots, v_n$ is distributed uniformly on
\begin{equation}
    S_+^{n-1}:=\{x=(x_1,\dots, x_n): x_i\in R, \|x\|_2=1, x_1>0\}.
\end{equation}

Comment: There are some results on bounds like this for singular values, see [chapters 4-6 of this](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) if this is relevant in your setting.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. But I am looking for the bounds on the eigenvectors but not eigenvalues. Here is a fact eigenvectors are distributed uniformly on the sphere.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yes! I find this result and I put it in my question. So they are sub-Gaussian? Because they are distributed uniformly on the sphere?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Sorry, I mean the inner product of the $v_1$ and one fix unit vector.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker So is it concentrated about $1/n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the distribution of $x=v_1\cdot u$, with $v_1$ of length $n$ uniformly distributed on the unit $n$-sphere and $u$ an arbitrary unit vector. This distribution is given by
$$P(x)=\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(n/2-1/2)}(1-x^2)^{n/2-3/2}\,\theta(1-x^2),\;\;n>1,$$
with $\theta(x)$ the unit step function. (Here is one [derivation.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359646/11260)) So for $n\gg 1$ this becomes a Gaussian, $P(x)\propto e^{-nx^2/2}$, with mean zero and variance $1/n$.

[image]

Plot of $P(x)$ for $n=2,3,5,10,20$ (larger $n$ gives more peaked distribution).

Comment: $P(x)dx$ is the probability that the random variable $v_1\cdot u$ is in the interval $(x,x+dx)$; so this is the probability density, not the cumulative distribution function

Comment: that paper addresses a completely different problem, where the eigenvectors are not uniformly distributed on the unit sphere.

Comment: section 2 is for the GOE, theorem 4.5 in section 4 is not for the GOE.

Comment: for large $n$ this probability saturates at 1, since it's a Gaussian of width $1/\sqrt n$ --- so you cannot make it any smaller.